# Phase change in a wave travelling through different media

Tags: visible-light

Suppose I have a wave, and two mediums with different indices of refraction. When the waves pass through these two mediums, will there be a phase change between the waves that comes out from the first medium, and those that comes out  from the second? I have drawn a picture representing the phenomenon. [image]

My teacher says that there will be a phase difference, since in the different mediums, the velocity of light is different and in the same time they travel different distances. However, this doesn't make much sense to me, since for all I know, the frequency (hence time period) remains constant upon changing media, thus if I consider the electric component of the wave (same phase for magnetic component),

$$ E(x,t) = E_0 \sin(kx + \omega t) = E_0 \sin(kx + 2 \pi f t) $$

The phase $kx + 2 \pi f t$ should remain the same irrespective of the media. Am I right, or is my teacher is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is right in that this is the way the world works. But you are right that he hasn't proved it.

It might have been better if he had said something like this. Suppose that like with a certain frequency hits two media. Suppose the frequency doesn't change and suppose light slows down by different amounts when traveling in the media. Given all that, you would expect to see a phase difference when light comes out the other side.

---

Here is why it is reasonable that wavelength changes, but frequency doesn't when light slows down. A beam of light has a series of crests and troughs flying toward you. You are very quick. With a stopwatch, you measure the time, $T$, it takes from one crest to the next. That is the period. Frequency, $f$, is the number of crests per second. Or equivalently, the number of periods per second.

$$f = 1/T$$

You know the speed of light, $c$. So you can figure out how far apart two crests are. That is the wavelength, $\lambda$.

$$\lambda = cT$$

Light hits a medium. You know how long between the arrival of successive crests. Light might well travel at some other speed, $v$, inside the medium.
If so, you can figure out how long until a crest reaches a depth $d$ inside. The next crest will take the same amount of time to get there. So the time between crests didn't change. $T$ and $f$ are the same.

Since light is traveling at $v$, you can figure out how far ahead one crest is from the next. That is the new wavelength.

$$\lambda = vT$$

---

Here is why you would expect a phase difference when light comes out of the two media.

Suppose light travels at slightly different speeds in the two media. The time it takes for a crest to reach the other side is slightly less in 1. By the time the crest has come out of 2, the crest from 1 has moved on and a trough is emerging. So now a crest matches a trough.

Actually, the speed difference is large. The frequency of light is very high. About a gazillion extra crests and troughs have emerged from 1 by the time it comes out of 2. So there it is pretty likely there will be a phase difference. You could get lucky and find that another crest is emerging from 1 at just the right time.